# $f_n:[-1,1] \to \Bbb R$ defined by $f_n(x)=\sqrt{x^2+1/n}$

Tags: real-analysis

This sequence of functions are uniformly convergent to $f(x)=|x|$. How to show directly that the derivative of this sequence does not converge uniformly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first have that
$$f_n'(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1/n}}$$
Define
$$f^*(x)=\begin{cases}-1& \text{if }x<0\\0&\text{if }x=0\\1&\text{if }x>0\end{cases}$$
We can clearly see that $f_n'\rightarrow f^*$ *pointwise*.
It is a general theorem that if $g_n\rightarrow g$ uniformly then $g_n\rightarrow g$ pointwise (It is also important that pointwise limits are unique).

To show that $f_n'$ does not converge uniformly, it then suffices to show that $f_n'\not\rightarrow f^*$ uniformly. In other words, we must show that $$\exists\epsilon>0\,\forall N\in\Bbb N\,\exists n\geq N\,\exists x\in[-1,1]\left(|f_n'(x)-f^*(x)|\geq\epsilon\right)$$

This is the difficult tedious part. We could choose any $\epsilon$ with $0<\epsilon<1$. Then given any $N\in\Bbb N$ we could choose $n=N$. With these choices we just need to find a point $x$ close enough to $0$. I'll leave it for you to verify that $x=\sqrt{\frac{(2-\epsilon)(1-\epsilon)^2}{N\epsilon}}$ works.

Answer (score 2):

- Indirect solution:
  If it was the case, the limit would be a derivable function in 0, which is not. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_differentiability), for example.
- Direct solution:
  let us consider the difference
  $$0\le f'(x)-f_n'(x) = \frac x{\sqrt{x^2}} - \frac x{\sqrt{x^2+ \frac 1n}}\\=
  x\frac {\sqrt{x^2+ \frac 1n} - \sqrt{x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+ \frac 1n}\sqrt{x^2}}
  \\=
  \frac 1n\frac 1{\sqrt{x^2+ \frac 1n} + \sqrt{x^2}} 
  \frac 1{\sqrt{x^2+ \frac 1n}}
  $$
  Now let us try to find the $\sup$ on $(0,1)$ of such quantity.
  As $$\sup_{x\in (0,1)}\frac 1n   \frac 1{\sqrt{x^2+ \frac 1n} + \sqrt{x^2}}<\infty $$
  then$$
  \sup_{(0,1)} |f'-f_n'|<\infty\iff
  \sup_{x\in (0,1)}\frac 1{\sqrt{x^2+ \frac 1n}}<\infty
  $$but $$\sup_{x\in (0,1)}\frac 1{\sqrt{x^2+ \frac 1n}}=\infty$$

Comment: OP wants a direct proof. This proof is by contradiction.

Comment: how do you know about that?

Comment: From the posted question: "How to show directly that..." means a direct proof is requested, as distinct from indirect (indirect = by contradiction).

Comment: is that better?

Comment: Yes now it's direct and a good approach (+1).

Answer (score 0):

Observe that each $f_n'(x)$ is continuous on $[-1, 1]$ so the uniform limit $g(x)$ should be continuous on $[-1, 1]$. But $g(x) = 1$ if $x > 0$, $-1$ if $x < 0$ and is 0 at $x = 0$ is clearly not continuous at $x = 0$.

So $g(x)$ is not continuous on $[-1, 1]$, and the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: I think you forgot the primes. You mean to refer to $f_n'(x)$ since it is $f'(x)$ which is either $-1$ or $1$ except at $0$.

Comment: @coffeemath: right, I forgot the prime sign.